# Check if any table has a user defined type

Tags: sql-server

I've seen on `sys.table_types` that I have 8 user-defined table types on my db.

How can I check if there is any table (1000+) on my db that are currently using any of these user-defined table types before dropping them.

Comment: How does a *table* use a table type? Surely you meant modules like procedures and functions?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if there is any table (1000+) on my db that are
>   currently using any of these user-defined table types before dropping
>   them.

**First things first**

> A table type is a type from which table variables or table-valued
>   parameters could be declared

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-table-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

This means that table types can be used by `table variables` / `TVP`'s and these can be used in parameter calls. An example of this is a stored procedure calling a `TVP`.

Table types are not permanent tables or used by permanent tables.

**sys.parameter_type_usages**

You can use the `sys.parameter_type_usages` dmv to get the parameters that are mapped to user defined types, these include `Table Valued Parameters`.

> Returns one row for each parameter that is of user-defined type.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-parameter-type-usages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ptu.object_id),tt.name
FROM sys.parameter_type_usages ptu
INNER JOIN sys.table_types tt
on ptu.user_type_id = tt.user_type_id;
```

**Testing**

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType 
   AS TABLE
      ( LocationName VARCHAR(50)
      , CostRate INT );
GO
/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertProductionLocation
   @TVP LocationTableType READONLY
      AS
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      INSERT INTO AdventureWorks.Production.Location
         (
            Name
            , CostRate
            , Availability
            , ModifiedDate
         )
      SELECT *, 0, GETDATE()
      FROM @TVP;
GO
```

*test statements from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)*

**Running the query at the top gives us both the procedure & the table type used**

```
(No column name)    name
usp_InsertProductionLocation    LocationTableType
```

The call to the procedure simply uses the table type and a self defined table variable:

```
DECLARE @LocationTVP AS LocationTableType;
/* Add data to the table variable. */
INSERT INTO @LocationTVP (LocationName, CostRate)
   SELECT Name, 0.00
   FROM AdventureWorks.Person.StateProvince;

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */
EXEC usp_InsertProductionLocation @LocationTVP;
```

*Statements also from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)*

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use `sys.expression_dependencies`:

```
SELECT s.name, o.name, def = OBJECT_DEFINITION(d.referencing_id) 
  FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
     ON d.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
     ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE d.referenced_database_name IS NULL
    AND d.referenced_schema_name = N'dbo'
    AND d.referenced_entity_name = N'MyType';
```

[*...stolen from myself...*](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6114/how-to-alter-user-defined-table-type-in-sql-server/)